# An explanation for the time complexity of the following algorithm

Tags: recursion, time-complexity

I have the following algorithm:

```py
def func(n):
    if n <= 1:
        return 1
    x = 0
    for i in range(n ** 2):
        if i % 4  == 0:
            x += i
    return x + func(n//3) + func(n//3) + func(n//3)
```

The complexity analysis is:

$ T(n) = n^2 + 3*T(\frac {n}{3}) + 1 $

I know that the complexity is $ O(n^2) $, but my question is how is it possible that without the recursive calls and with them the complexity is the same? Is there any intuitive explanation for this?

Answer (score 0):

An algorithm complexity is the time/space of the most expensive operation. If other operations are less expensive comparing to it, they do not affect the algorithm complexity.

E.g. If an algorithm runs in `T(n) = n^2 + log(n)` -> `O(n)=n^2` since `log(n)` will not affect `n^2` since it's too much lower than it as the variable `n` increases.

Even if `T(n) = n^2 + 3n^2 = 4n^2` -> `O(n)=n^2` because the scalar `4` will not take the complexity to another quantitive level, as the dependency of the variable n (the most important and expensive part) is equal.